# how to set the page title based on the previous page in angular 8

Tags: angular8

```
apply for job     interested job
    \               /
     \             /        
      \           /
        attach CV
```

I have a component "attach-cv" that allows user to attach CV.

There are 2 ways you can land on this page either from "apply for job" or from "interested job".
Based on the page from where the user came to attach-cv I want to set the page title.

I tried setting the title using a service, but the title disappears as I refresh the page.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 routes to the same component, added different title to each.

```
{
    path: 'apply-for-job/attachment',
    component: CVAttachmentComponent,
    data: { title: "Apply for job" },
},

{
    path: 'interested-job/attachment',
    component: CVAttachmentComponent,
    data: { title: "Interested job" },
},
```

With this, the component is reused and the title doesn't disappear after page refresh